# Save application logs to s3 before instace termination

Tags: amazon-web-services

A scenario for java application:
I have multiple EC2 Running instances ( On-demand ) If load comes then one spot instance automatically launch and java Application should be run on that spot instance once the load is normal then SPOT instance will be terminated automatically. The purpose of Saving Cost optimization
2) Application Logs will be there (Spot instance), that logs will be saved in s3.
3) We need to find how Autoscale can happen in case memory usage is high?

kindly suggest your views for the same
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a good idea is to keep logs in `CloudWatch`.

You can do it with `SLF4J`.

More: https://dzone.com/articles/logging-to-aws-cloudwatch-logs

Comment: Thanks, will check this article

Comment: no problem :)  CloudWatch is really convenient to explore logs as well.

Answer (score 2):

To complement @ŁukaszOlszewski answer, the other way would be to use [Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html). The documentation even specifies downloading logs from instance before its fully terminated as an example of the hooks usage:

> a lifecycle hook pauses the instance before it is terminated. While the instance is in the wait state, you can, for example, connect to the instance and **download logs or other data before the instance is fully terminated**.

The downloading operation can be performed using [SSM Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) in a lambda function triggered by the hook.

Comment: Thanks, will check this article

Comment: Rather than downloading the logs, is there a way to directly push the logs to CW before instance termination via CW agent?